# Body scrolls above the company header

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

When visiting a company page ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/xometry-inc)) and scrolling down, the top nav bar (Jobs, Companies, Saved Jobs, etc.) disappears, and the main body & right sidebar can be seen through the hole where the top nav bar used to be, above the company header (in this case Xometry, Inc.).

[image]

This happens only when [top bar stickiness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) is disabled.

I am currently using Chrome for macOS 89.0.4389.114

Comment: How did you manage to hide the main site header? With the search bar and the notification icon

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson "Disable top bar stickiness" is a [site setting on your user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current). If it's disabled, I can repro this bug. :)

Comment: @Catija not anymore, I guess :( [We’ve removed the option to disable the fixed top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368973/786798)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this!

The Jobs sticky header is pushed down 50px to make room for the site-wide sticky header. I had no idea it was possible to un-stick that header in the settings! I've updated the code so the Jobs header is only pushed down when the global header is sticky.